# Не выполняется код JavaScript (JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Имею вот такой код:

```
$.getJSON = function (json, goodsOut) {

}

function init() {
    $.getJSON("goods.json", goodsOut);
}

function goodsOut(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var out='';
    for (var key in data) {
        out +='<div class="cart">';
        out +=`<p class="name">${data[key].name}</p>`;
        out +=`<img src="images/${data[key].image}" alt="">`;
        out +=`<div class="cost">${data[key].cost}</div>`;
        out +='<button class="buy-it">Купить</button>';
        out +='</div>';
    }
    $('.output').html(out);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    init();
}
```

Это что-то типа карточки товара и кнопка "Купить" снизу. По непонятным для меня причинам этот код не работает. Ошибок в консоли нет, а на сайте в `.output`ничего не выводится.

Вот содержимое `goods.json`

```
{
    "account" : {
        "name" : "123",
        "cost" : 123,
        "stats" : "Текст",
        "image" : "img/json.png",
        "order" : 1
    }
}
```

В этой теме я совсем новичок, поэтому все очень плохо :)

P.S.: в html файле только `<div class="output"></div>`

Comment: Я не вижу в этом коде ни единой строки, которая бы вызывала функцию goodsOut, которая собственно и должна выводить что то

Comment: Добавил

$(document).ready(function () {
    goodsOut(data);
});

 не помогло :\

Comment: Без параметров конечно не поможет. Ведь эта функция на вход принимает параметр data в котором как раз должен содержаться объект созданный из того самого json. Но вот кода получающего json, парсящего его в объект и вызывающего goodsOut с этим объектом все еще не наблюдается. У вас под это дело видимо предусматривалась функция getJSON, но вот почему в ней нет ни одной строки кода это загадка. Я так подозреваю, она должна отправить запрос на сервер (ajax) и при получении данных отдать их уже goodsOut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение - уберите из Вашего кода эти три строчки:

```
//$.getJSON = function (json, goodsOut) {
//
//}
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: спасибо что откликнулись, приятно)
но эти строчки добавил мне редактор (php storm). Я их убрал. Теперь у меня подчёркиваются все знаки $ и в браузере вот такая ошибка  SCRIPT5009: '$' is not defined. Я уже настолько в тупике, что не знаю что с ней делать(

Comment: jquery вроде подключен, ошибок нигде больше нет

Comment: так в общем я разобрался, убрал эти строчки и подключил jquery сразу двумя способами, все заработало)

Comment: @Красаучик "подключил jquery сразу двумя способами" - это неправильно, подключение jQuery должно быть одно, но работающее )

Comment: ля, работает и на том спасибо) не буду трогать пока